# django - Adding a new user

Tags: django, django-models

My problem is really simple I guess, but I am having a hard time solving it. Please have a look at my model:

models.py:

```
class ThreadParticipant(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I can create a ThreadParticipant with a new user. But how do I create another new user for that ThreadParticipant? When I try to create it through the admin, the one that I select, only becomes the user of that thread instead of adding it to that `threadparticipant`. Please help me solve it. Thank you.

**Edit:**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add ?

Comment: @ssice Thank you for your answer! How do I do that for the admin.

Comment: Your last paragraph is fuzzy. Please detail what you do, what happens and what you expect. But I think you want to use inlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you don't obfuscate users from your Threads model via this third model if all your interested in is thread and user objects.

Your model would look like the following:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
     *** other items in model***
     user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

With this embodiment, run:

`>>> manage.py shell`

`>>> from YOUR_MODEL.models import Thread`

`>>> t = Thread.objects.get(pk = THREAD-ID-NUMBER)` ***for testing, just use 1. it will be the first you've entered***

`>>> user_to_add = User.objects.get(username = 'WHOMEVER')` ***username for the user you want to add***

`>>> t.user.add(user_to_add)`

`>>> t.save()` ***dont forget to save***

It seems like you are just getting started with Django. My suggestion is to run some exercises (like the above) with basic models in the shell. These commands are what you will eventually place in your views, such that Django will automate these things.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was learning from a blog and it had another class to hold the participants for that particular thread. And thanks to you, I have removed the `ThreadParticipant` class from the models. Please answer just one more question, how do I get the Thread with the latest message for that user? I have added it in the edit. Thank you.

Comment: run in shell: Thread.objects.get(user = USER-OF-INTEREST) this will return all the threads that user has participated in. There are lots of ways to sort this data (publish date, creation date, etc etc). Too many to list here. Check out the Django documentation on querysets here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/